# How long does the warning for incorrect flagging last?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

Recently, I noticed that when I flag a question, I get a nice little warning at the bottom:

[image: flag warning]

I find this a bit strange, because out of all the flags I've cast, only 3 have been explicitly rejected. One of them is a *too broad* on a question [I still believe is too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974914/debug-a-python-script-called-from-java-processbuilder-eclipse), but both the flag and the question are from 2015. The other two are from VLQ flags I dropped when I didn't quite understand the "*question is very low quality*" link in the help and improvement queue. Those are more recent, but it's still only two flags.

It seems a bit odd to me that just two declined flags would trigger this warning. I don't have many flags altogether, but that's still only ~1% of my flags declined. Any idea how long this warning will last? It doesn't count disputed flags does it?

Note I can still flag just fine. I have not been flag banned. This seems to be a warning that doesn't want to go away

Comment: I don't think the % matters. I'd say it is an absolute number... 'if X flags have been declined in the past Y days, display this'

Comment: Just raise some some 100% success flags. Comments with "accept" in it or that start with "+1" ... or lurk a bit in [NATO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/126814) for NAA flags ... that should make that warning go away.

Comment: Are you still getting this warning when you attempt to flag? Looking in my tools, it says that you shouldn't be getting any such warning. Moderators can see who should be getting flag warnings and flag bans, and I don't see either in your profile. It could be just a matter of timing, with the three flags being declined in a batch in the middle of others being processed.

Comment: @BradLarson as of now it seems I no longer get that warning. It seems to have gone away sometime this morning

Comment: *"[Flaggers with a recent (past 7 days) flagging history consisting of at least 10 handled flags where >= 10% of flags were declined will see the following when they flag:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405)"*. So you'll see this flag if you've only had 10 flags reviewed in the last week even 1 declined will make this message show

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me a while back shortly after the moderator elections this year wrapped up and the new mods started handling some of my months-old post flags.

If you flag at least 10 flags in a week, this filter will start checking your flag history/status; for people who flag less than 10 flags in a given week, the filter will not apply.

Now here's where it gets tricky. If at least 10% of your *handled* flags in the last week are declined, you'll get a warning. The flags that get handled **don't have to be the ones you raised that week**.

Likewise, if at least 25% of your *handled* flags are declined ones in the last week, you'll get a flag ban for that type of flag. Declined post flags won't cause you to get flag banned for comments, for example.

You can see the flags that are counting toward the ban or warning at this URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/<your-user-id>?showDeclined=true
```

Where you would put your own user ID in place of the `<your-user-id>` fragment.

Unfortunately this doesn't appear to be linked anywhere on the Flags page. The "Declined flags" links on the side take you to different pages than the one above.

Comment: `showDeclined=true` doesn't work for me - it just returns an empty page. `?status=3`, however, shows all declined flags.

Comment: Something just occurred to me while reading your answer... theoretically, a moderator could exploit this and either serve a user a flag ban for a certain duration by selectively handling unhelpful flags at strategic times, or avert a ban by handling enough helpful flags between unhelpful ones. I personally couldn't be bothered counting my flags enough to do that - if a user is bad enough at flagging, I'm probably declining 80-100% of their flags regardless of timeframe.

Comment: (I'm still annoyed at the fact that [users who flag seldom enough will be completely immune to flag bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261760/users-with-100-flag-decline-rates-will-never-know-their-flags-are-being-decline) - since there's just this one very short-term ban in place.)

Comment: @Rob It may be different for moderators; that is the page that the ban message linked me to that I have bookmarked. I picked it over one of the aggregate declined flag pages because it focuses only on the flags that are contributing to the ban or the warning.

Comment: @TylerH Ah interesting. So I suppose the page *is* working.. it's just correctly blank for me, as I've got no recent declined flags.

Comment: @Rob if you can find a post flag of mine that is still pending and decline it, I can take a screenshot to show what it will look like. I know it'll be hard for a mod to test that out since your flags don't get reviewed.

Comment: @TylerH You don't have any pending flags.. but even so, I wouldn't be comfortable declining a valid flag for science. Anyway, I'm able to view that page for other users, and found someone with a recent declined flag. The page looks identical to the `?status=3` page, except for the title. It doesn't show you how close you are to the warning/ban - or any other information - so a screenshot of the flagging summary page should suffice if you'd like.

Comment: @Rob Ah, gotcha. And I wouldn't have minded making an invalid post flag for science :-) If I get one in the near future I will try to remember to add a screenshot here; likewise if you have a view that is anonymized feel free to add a screenshot or any additional/corrected info to this answer.